# DeserializeObject Newtonsoft fail when try to deserialize HttpResponseMessage obtained from HttpClient

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net, dotnet-httpclient

The following code to make [deserialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaK5u.png) is producing the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhPbU.png) when executed.

The purpose is get the result coming from httpClient of .Net(client) and transform it to make a comparison in the test case, but when executed the error is presented

Comment: Hi @Guilherme Dino, how is your api(v1.0/Administrator) result like? Also how is your model design? Could you pls share enough code and do not share it in the picture? Besides, what's the version of asp.net core you use?

Comment: It has issue with Json and you have not posted it. When you read response to deserilize what is that ? Also important how you structure your class.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't just use external links to compose a question. Just write a clear complete question, with all necessary details.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue, some extra explanation about the code being executed:

The same code was running in another test case using xunit, the test environment was replacing databases to in memory database and, the name was being generated using timestamp associated with a default string.

Running the tests concurrently, the database name was the same, it explains why running isolated works perfectly, and running all tests the test fail

I just specify the name to all memory database, and it solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).